# How to validate the choice column in SharePoint 2016 custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, 2016, validation

I'm struggling with the following issue: there is a need to create a participation list for my stuff for the upcoming training. The conference room has 18 seats. There are three training sessions available for each day.

I've created few choice columns with three different hours available.

The example would be- the name of the column is **04May** and the choices are:

```
0900-1000 
1100-1200 
1300-1400
```

I tried to use the following formula in Column Validation section:

```
=IF([04May]="0900-1000",COUNTIF([04May],"0900-1000")<=18,IF([04May]="1100-1200",COUNTIF([04May],"1100-1200")<=18,IF([04May]="1300-1400",COUNTIF([04May],"1300-1400")<=18,TRUE)))
```

No success. Error message :( Where do I make a mistake? Please Help.

Comment: Are you trying to check values from another rows/list items in formula? If yes, unfortunately it is not supported in SharePoint formulas. You can only read values from same row/list item.

Comment: It's the same list. There is a choice column inside- 04May. There are three mentioned choices. For each choice: there must be a limitation of maximum 18 entries.

Comment: I know same **list**. But I think you are trying to get values from multiple **items** in same **list**, which is not supported.

Comment: what would you suggest? will a choice column (yes/no) for each session would be a solution?

Comment: As you are using SharePoint 2016, you will be able to add custom JavaScript of list form. You can override PreSaveAction() function to check count of existing list items with the values you want and then restrict saving forms.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint validation formulas.

You cannot get column values from another rows/list items (from same or different SharePoint list) in formula, this is a known limitation of formulas in SharePoint:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your formula is that the COUNTIF function needs to reference the entire column, not just the single cell. You can modify the formula as follows to check the count of all occurrences of the chosen time slot across all rows:

```
=IF([04May] = "0900-1000", COUNTIF([04May], "0900-1000") <= 18, IF([04May] = "1100-1200", COUNTIF([04May], "1100-1200") <= 18, IF([04May] = "1300-1400", COUNTIF([04May], "1300-1400") <= 18, TRUE, FALSE), FALSE), FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Error message :/